# How do I uninstall code block completely from Ubuntu 14.04(Including plugins)

Tags: uninstall, code-blocks

I install code block with some plugins .but There is a problem with codeblock. so i want to uninstall codeblock completely so that i can install it from begining with new codeblock window.

Comment: but it doesn't install from beginingI install from Ubuntu software center

Comment: But there is no option of remove/uninstall

Answer (score 8):

To remove a package completely, you can use

```
sudo apt-get purge <packagename>
```

**Example**:

```
sudo apt-get purge codeblocks
```

To remove a package plus its dependencies, you can use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove <packagename>
```

**Example**:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove codeblocks
```

Read the official documentation first here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto.

Comment: Does removing  codeblocks and its dependencies break some other applications? I think we just need to use the purge command.